# Extracting an orthogonal (or semi-orthogonal) subset from a large matrix that is not orthogonal

Tags: r, matrix, orthogonal

I have written a script that generates all possible combinations of elements (col) in a matrix within a range (min and max) of interest. Here is a very simple example:

```
mat <- expand.grid(seq(0,10,5),seq(0,10,5),seq(0,10,5))
```

How to identify a semi-orthogonal or orthogonal (if possible) subset in this matrix.

In my actual code, the matrix has 13 cols and over 300 million rows.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The question could be made clearer. In the 1st place of "combinations", is it really "combinations"? Maybe, "permutations" suits there better. Also, `combn(n,k)`, but what is k in your situation where n=13? With simple prototype via numbers of what you mean, you can make the case clearer.

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER thanks for the comment, let me clarify. I used the expand.grid() function to get possible combinations of elements within range of interest. I edited the original post to show an example.